# One in ten Americans “think” or “thinks”?

Tags: grammar

[image]

I wonder when actor is a 3rd person singular number in this sentence, verb should be ending with the suffix -s or -es or not.

Whats the rule?

Comment: This isn't referring to a specific group of 10 Americans, one of whom believes a certain idea: here "1 in 10 Americans" means "10% of _all_ Americans" (roughly 30 million people), hence why the plural form is used.

Comment: @psmears  Simple agreement dictates that the verb is plural because the head of the NP is the plural "Americans". However, singular override is possible, presumably due to the presence of singular "one".

Comment: You've approved a partly wrong answer. There is no 'adjectival phrase in your example. "One in ten" is a determinative phrase determining the nominal, the plural "Americans".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both a singular and plural verb are possible.

**One {in ten Americans} thinks that** ... Here "in 10 Americans" is a *non-defining* adjectival phrase modifying the subject "One". This is based upon taking a random sample of any 10 Americans of whom one individual "thinks that..."

**{One in ten Americans} think that** ... Here "in 10 Americans" is a *defining* adjectival phrase modifying the subject "One", and the subject is "One in ten Americans" which is a numerous group of about 30 million.

Comment: That has to be the weirdest analysis I've seen in a long while!

Answer (score 3):

> [*One in ten Americans*] *think(s) *HTML is a sexually transmitted* disease*.

The head of the bracketed NP is the plural "Americans", so the simple agreement rule would suggest that plural "think" is correct.

However, the verb can be singular as well as plural, the optional singular override probably being motivated by the presence of "one".

Edit: For those interested in the syntax, "one in ten" is a DP (determinative phrase) in which the PP "in ten" is in post-head modifier function. The DP functions as determiner in the NP subject "one in ten Americans", whose head is "Americans".